# Fcitx5 couldn't work well in Kubuntu2204

Tags: kubuntu, chinese, fcitx

Fcitx5 could't work well in Kubuntu.
I have installed many packages which Fcitx5 depended on,However,it still could't input Chinese in some software.
I can input Chinese in Neovim ,Chrome, and many software,but,I can't make it in Vscode or some similar software.
I tired to fix it,and i follow Manjaro's config,But it still not work.
It ask me to write /etc/environment.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gGj8.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTPdP.jpg)
But,ubuntu can't find IM.

I hope for your help,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Ubuntu, you should just use the tool [im-config](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/im-config) provided by ubutnu that designed for it. It will be much easier. See also [fcitx's own wiki](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Setup_Fcitx_5#im-config_.28Debian.2FDebian-based.2FUbuntu.29).

Basically what you need to do is to run `im-config`, in the popup, answer "yes" to the first question, then select fcitx5.

Also, you will need to make sure `fcitx5-frontend-{gtk3,qt5}` are installed, usually this are all installed as long as you didn't pass any additional parameter when running `apt-get install fcitx5`.

Since you are using Chinese system and kubuntu, `fcitx5-chinese-addons` and `kde-config-fcitx5` are two package you probably also want. First one contains common Chinese input method, the second one provides the integration to kde's `systemsettings`. If you need any other engines, see [this page](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Input_method_engines) for the complete list.

After running `im-config` and select "activate fcitx5", logout or reboot the system, and you should see fcitx5 running and it should be ready to use. You may still need to add some Chinese input method to your input method list. You can do that by right-clicking on the tray icon and selecting "Configure", or using systemsettings and looking for "Input Method" under "Regional settings".

e.g. if you want to use "pinyin", click "add input method" and Search for "pinyin". In kde's systemsettings, it should looks like this:

[image: systemsettings].

Then you should be ready to go.

Since you mentioned you're using /etc/environment, I think you didn't use the right syntax for it and you're having extra space around "=". I'd just suggest you just remove anything you added there and use `im-config` instead.